# How to get Featherlight Image Gallery to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the image gallery functionality from Featherlight to work. It is a jQuery add-on and I've followed their directives from their web-site (http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) but unfortunately I can't get it to work as intended. What I'm trying to achieve is an image gallery presentation by clicking on an image thumb. From the gallery I should be able to navigate among the images included in the gallery with previous, next icons. I've added links to the css-style file as well as the js-file. Enterd the HTML-code for the gallery and added javascript code for settings to the gallery. 
I'm a newbie to javascript so it may be some very basic thing and I would really appreciate any hint on what is wrong.
Code can be found at:
 http://jsfiddle.net/ovedexlin/69qZx/

HTML-code:

```
<div class="adImages">
            <div class="row">
              <a class="thumbnail gallery" href="http://www.tranarportalen.se/UpLoad/Breeders/b11000/digger.jpg">
              <img src="http://www.tranarportalen.se/UpLoad/Breeders/b11000/digger.jpg" alt="thumb1" width="250" height="200">
              </a>
              <a class="thumbnail gallery" href="http://www.tranarportalen.se/UpLoad/Breeders/b11000/digger.jpg">
              <img src="http://www.tranarportalen.se/UpLoad/Breeders/b11000/digger.jpg" alt="thumb2" width="250" height="200">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

JS-code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.gallery').featherlightGallery({
    gallery: {
        previous: '«',
        next: '»',
        fadeIn: 300
    },
    openSpeed: 300
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine (though you may want to set width and hight with css), but you didn't include the `featherlight.gallery.min.js`, just the css.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z28D7/